# Seach Bar in react-native doesn't show any result

Tags: react-native

When I search for a name nothing appears and everything gets deleted. Also, when I delete what I typed nothing appears again.
This is the search part I hope it's understandable!

```
  const handleSearch = text => {
                const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
                const filteredData = filter(fullData, user => {
                  return contains(user, formattedQuery);
                });
                setData(filteredData);
                setQuery(text);
              };
```

I think the problem lays here but I don't know what to change exactly

```
const contains = ({ name }, query) => {
                const { first, last } = name;
              
                if (first.includes(query) || last.includes(query) ) {
                  return true;
                }
              
                return false;
              };
                  return (
                    <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',
                      padding: 10,
                      marginVertical: 10,
                      borderRadius: 20
                    }}
                  >
                    <TextInput
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      clearButtonMode="always"
                      value={query}
                      onChangeText={queryText => handleSearch(queryText)}
                      placeholder="Search"
                      style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
                    />
```

Comment: The indentation in this code makes it hard to read. The bodies of the handleSearch and contains functions are indented too far, and the return statement is indented way too much. I'd suggest fixing the indentation to make the question easier to read if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you haven't done filtering correctly.

```
const handleSearch = text => {
     const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
     const filteredData = fullData.filter(user => contains(user, formattedQuery));
     setData(filteredData);
     setQuery(text);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm getting an error "undefined is not an object evaluating (fullData.filter)" what to do about it?